# AMPscript subtring - everything but first 4 characters

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way to capture in a variable everything from an unknown length string but the first 4 characters, using AMPscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.

What you would need to do is first find the [length](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/length/) of the string and then use [SubString](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/substring/) to cut off the first four characters.

Example:

```
%%[
    SET @String = "CUT-This is shown"
    SET @length = LENGTH(@String)
    SET @substr = Substring(@String,5,@length)
    /* You need to set it to 5 as the parameter is the first displayed digit, not the total removed. Setting to four would still display the 4th character */
    OUTPUT(@substr)
]%%
```

Which will output:

```
This is shown
```